# Advice wanted on advanced Linux certification/courses including RHCA

Tags: linux

I have been working in Linux administration for 2.5 years. I would like to have a certification in this. Yes RHCE is an option. I think I already know most of the RHCE stuff.

But I would like to have something advanced. I am ready for a full time course as I am not getting the exposure in my current company.

Please give me suggestions about training/courses.

I have found a course called RHCA(Architect). Is this a good course?

Comment: Hello nitins. Great to have you here. I just edited your post a little bit to clean up the grammar, some punctuation and make the title more descriptive. Hopefully you'll get more people to look at the post that way. =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without having the RHCE, it is awfully presumptive to say that it is not very advanced, especially with only ~2 years experience.  You will likely find it to be more challenging than you anticipate and it is a requisite for the RHCA track.

Currently, I like both the [Linux Professional Institute](http://www.lpi.org/) and Red Hat's [certification](http://www.redhat.com/certification/) tracks.

With LPI, I prefer it because it is distribution agnostic and has a good generalist focus.  The exam style is well done and would be difficult to get through without having supporting experience.  LPIC-1 and LPIC-2 are both well aligned with general Linux system administration.  LPIC-3 is the higher-level track, which is more specialist focus.  Historically, I have not liked its high weight on LDAP but that is changing somewhat.

The "hands-on" approach with RHCE has a lot of value.  Someone who is proficient in Linux but not as experienced may be surprised, as it is specifically designed to weed out people who do not have a good foundation of working knowledge.  While you may be able to "figure out" all things eventually, the time limitation will prevent success without an existing proficiency.  RHCA is expensive to pursue.  It is something I am working on now and is time consuming as well as challenging.  The specialist endorsements insure more specific knowledge of the topics they cover.  With this, however, there is an unavoidable focus on Red Hat technologies and methods.

There is not a lot of LPIC-3 or RHCA.  They both take serious commitment and a working knowledge to successful acquire.  Were I to see either of these on a person's resume, I would certainly give it additional attention automatically.

For training, Red Hat has training for their exams.  Third parties offer LPI training but you may find it difficult to find training specific to LPIC-3.  Additional information is available on both of their Web sites.

Comment: +1. I'm an RHCE and having over 10 yr of exp still can say it is a challenging exam...

Answer (score 1):

you have to be RHCE to get RHCA. and RHCA is not a single course, it's several different examinations

Comment: Yes I know RCHE is needed